# Dividing the MAE by the average of the values

Tags: regression, error, mape, mae

I would like to parse the MAE (Mean Absolute Error) to a percentage value. I know there is the MAPE (Mean Absolute Percentage Error), however it has some drawbacks as going to infinity if one of my values is zero. I had the idea of dividing the MAE by the average of my values, but I could not find any reference on that.

The formula I intended to use is the following, having $y$ as the real value and $\bar y$ as the prediction:

$\frac{MAE}{AVG(y)} = \frac{\frac{\lvert y_1 -\bar y_1\rvert + \lvert y_2 -\bar y_2\rvert}{n}}{\frac{\lvert y_1 + y_2\rvert}{n}} = \frac{\lvert y_1 -\bar y_1\rvert + \lvert y_2 -\bar y_2\rvert}{\lvert y_1 + y_2\rvert} = \sum{\frac{\lvert y -\bar y\rvert}{\sum{\lvert y\rvert}}}$

Using this, the percentage Error could only get to infinity if all y values are 0 which will never happen in my dataset. Please note that I cannot have negative Values for $y$ and $\bar y$ in my dataset, so the difference will always be the true difference.

In the end I want to say for example: "the average error in my prediction is 10%"

Does anyone have any sources that this was done before? Is there some serious drawbacks to it or do I overlook anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shameless piece of self-promotion: [Kolassa & Schütz (2007, *Foresight*)](https://ideas.repec.org/a/for/ijafaa/y2007i6p40-43.html) call this quantity the "MAD/Mean" or "weighted MAPE" (because it is) and discuss it.

As to drawbacks, the wMAPE, as a scaled MAD, will reward biased forecasts if your future distribution is asymmetrical, just like the "plain" MAD ([Kolassa, 2020, *IJF*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2019.02.017)). [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352) is related.

(Yes, I do have a *thing* for forecast accuracy measures.)

Feel free to ping me for the papers on ResearchGate.

Comment: Hi Stephan, thank you so much for leading me in the right direction. I messaged you on ResearchGate.

Comment: Upvoted for the excellent utility of the answer.